# PHP and Codeigniter in action

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I've been reading a lot of the Codeigniter user manual, and while it's very intuitive and helpful, I learn best by doing and seeing.  Are there some good example sites out there with source that I can browse through and see how it all comes together?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried their [video tutorials](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out NETTuts and their "From Scratch" series. Very useful for new users.

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/