# Codeigniter and MVC learning

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have been studying codeigniter and MVC architecture but it's confusing me. I just need a link or place where i can learn it easily and with a lot of practicals

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

[PHP & codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732433/php-and-codeigniter-in-action)

[CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html)

[Codeigniter MVC wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MVC)

[Codeigniter's MVC](http://www.jimohalloran.com/2007/09/06/how-i-use-codeigniters-mvc/)

Hope these help!